# Attribute Error With Beautiful Soup And Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I had a working piece of code, and then I run it today and it's broken. I have pulled out the relevant section that is giving me problems.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

webpage = requests.get('http://www.bbcgoodfood.com/search/recipes?query=')

soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage.content) 
links = soup.find("div",{"class":"main row grid-padding"}).find_all("h2",{"class":"node-title"})

for link in links:
    print(link.a["href"])
```

This gives me an error "Attribute Error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'"

What precisely is this error telling me?

find_all() is a valid command in the beautiful soup documentation.
Looking through the webpage's source code, my path to my desired object seems to make sense.

I think something must have changed with the website, because I don't see how my code could just stop working. But I don't understand the error message that well...

Thanks for any help you can give!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when you tried to access the page, it gives you `permission denied`, so the `soup.find()` returns nothing `None`, and `None` has no attribute of `find_all()`, this gives you an `AttributeError`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

webpage = requests.get('http://www.bbcgoodfood.com/search/recipes?query=')


print webpage.content
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Access Denied</H1>

You don't have permission to access "http&#58;&#47;&#47;www&#46;bbcgoodfood&#46;com&#47;search&#47;recipes&#63;" on this server.<P>
Reference&#32;&#35;18&#46;4fa9cd17&#46;1428789762&#46;680369dc
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

If you resolve this by adding a header with proper user agent like @Vader suggested, your code will then run fine:

```
...
headers = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
webpage = requests.get('http://www.bbcgoodfood.com/search/recipes?query=', headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage.content) 
links = soup.find("div",{"class":"main row grid-padding"}).find_all("h2",{"class":"node-title"})

for link in links:
    print(link.a["href"])

/recipes/4942/lemon-drizzle-cake
/recipes/3092/ultimate-chocolate-cake
/recipes/3228/chilli-con-carne
/recipes/3229/yummy-scrummy-carrot-cake
/recipes/1223/bestever-brownies
/recipes/1167651/chicken-and-chorizo-jambalaya
/recipes/2089/spiced-carrot-and-lentil-soup
/recipes/1521/summerinwinter-chicken
/recipes/1364/spicy-root-and-lentil-casserole
/recipes/4814/mustardstuffed-chicken
/recipes/4622/classic-scones-with-jam-and-clotted-cream
/recipes/333614/red-lentil-chickpea-and-chilli-soup
/recipes/5605/falafel-burgers
/recipes/11695/raspberry-bakewell-cake
/recipes/4686/chicken-biryani
```

Comment: Does that mean somebody at their end reacted to my usage of the site?

Thanks for your help - I need to find somewhere to learn about this more, as I don't really understand what you've done

Comment: @Jacobadtr, Yes and No, many webserver (or their firewall etc.) will simply reject request from suspicious user-agent automatically to avoid bot scanning etc. How they collect and use the stats is another question. If you want to learn web crawling, wikipedia or w3c is a good place to start.

Answer (score 2):

The site you are trying to parse doesn't "like" your user agent and returns 403 error,then parser fails since it cannot find the `div`. Try to change user-agent to an user-agent of one of the browsers:

```
webpage = requests.get('http://www.bbcgoodfood.com/search/recipes?query=', headers = {'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'})
```